# Why is a statement like 1 + n *= 3 allowed in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

The precedence tables in many Ruby documentations out there list binary arithmetic operations as having higher precedence than their corresponding compound assignment operators. This leads me to believe that code like this shouldn't be valid Ruby code, yet it is.

```
1 + age *= 2
```

If the precedence rules were correct, I'd expect that the above code would be parenthesized like this:

```
((1 + age) *= 2) #ERROR: Doesn't compile
```

But it doesn't.

So what gives?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Checking `ruby -y` output, you can see exactly what is happening. Given the source of `1 + age *= 2`, the output suggests this happens (simplified):

`tINTEGER` found, recognised as `simple_numeric`, which is a `numeric`, which is a `literal`, which is a `primary`. Knowing that `+` comes next, `primary` is recognised as `arg`.

`+` found. Can't deal yet.

`tIDENTIFIER` found. Knowing that next token is `tOP_ASGN` (operator-assignment), `tIDENTIFIER` is recognised as `user_variable`, and then as `var_lhs`.

`tOP_ASGN` found. Can't deal yet.

`tINTEGER` found. Same as last one, it is ultimately recognised as `primary`. Knowing that next token is `\n`, `primary` is recognised as `arg`.

At this moment we have `arg + var_lhs tOP_ASGN arg` on stack. In this context, we recognise the last `arg` as `arg_rhs`. We can now pop `var_lhs tOP_ASGN arg_rhs` from stack and recognise it as `arg`, with stack ending up as `arg + arg`, which can be reduced to `arg`.

`arg` is then recognised as `expr`, `stmt`, `top_stmt`, `top_stmts`. `\n` is recognised as `term`, then `terms`, then `opt_terms`. `top_stmts opt_terms` are recognised as `top_compstmt`, and ultimately `program`.

---

On the other hand, given the source `1 + age * 2`, this happens:

`tINTEGER` found, recognised as `simple_numeric`, which is a `numeric`, which is a `literal`, which is a `primary`. Knowing that `+` comes next, `primary` is recognised as `arg`.

`+` found. Can't deal yet.

`tIDENTIFIER` found. Knowing that next token is `*`, `tIDENTIFIER` is recognised as `user_variable`, then `var_ref`, then `primary`, and `arg`.

`*` found. Can't deal yet.

`tINTEGER` found. Same as last one, it is ultimately recognised as `primary`. Knowing that next token is `\n`, `primary` is recognised as `arg`.

The stack is now `arg + arg * arg`. `arg * arg` can be reduced to `arg`, and the resultant `arg + arg` can also be reduced to `arg`.

`arg` is then recognised as `expr`, `stmt`, `top_stmt`, `top_stmts`. `\n` is recognised as `term`, then `terms`, then `opt_terms`. `top_stmts opt_terms` are recognised as `top_compstmt`, and ultimately `program`.

---

What's the critical difference? In the first piece of code, `age` (a `tIDENTIFIER`) is recognised as `var_lhs` (left-hand-side of assignment), but in the second one, it's `var_ref` (a variable reference). Why? Because Bison is a LALR(1) parser, meaning that it has one-token look-ahead. So `age` is `var_lhs` because Ruby saw `tOP_ASGN` coming up; and it was `var_ref` when it saw `*`. This comes about because Ruby knows (using the huge [state transition table](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~spopuri/cparser.html#bison-tables) that Bison generates) that one specific production is impossible. Specifically, at this time, the stack is `arg + tIDENTIFIER`, and next token is `*=`. If `tIDENTIFIER` is recognised as `var_ref` (which leads up to `arg`), and `arg + arg` reduced to `arg`, then there is no rule that starts with `arg tOP_ASGN`; thus, `tIDENTIFIER` cannot be allowed to become `var_ref`, and we look at the next matching rule (the `var_lhs` one).

So Aleksei is partly right in that there is *some* truth to "when it sees a syntax error, it tries another way", but it is limited to one token into future, and the "attempt" is just a lookup in the state table. Ruby is incapable of complex repair strategies we humans use to understand sentences like ["the horse raced past the barn fell"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence), where we happily parse till the last word, then reevaluate the whole sentence when the first parse turns out impossible.

tl;dr: The precedence table is not exactly correct. There is no place in Ruby source where it exists; rather, it is the result of the interplay of various parsing rules. Many of the precedence rules break in when left-hand-side of an assignment is introduced.

Comment: See also https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/LR-Table-Construction.html#LR-Table-Construction

Comment: [Shouldn't the TL;DR be at the top of the answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137120/tldr-summaries-at-the-top-of-question)

Answer (score 9):

The simplified answer is. You can only assign a value to a variable, not to an expression. Therefore the order is `1 + (age *= 2)`. The precedence only comes into play if multiple options are possible. For example `age *= 2 + 1` can be seen as `(age *= 2) + 1` or `age *= (2 + 1)`, since multiple options are possible and the `+` has a higher precedence than `*=`, `age *= (2 + 1)` is used.

Answer (score 5):

**NB This answer should not be marked as solving the issue. See the answer by @Amadan for the correct explanation.**

I am not sure what “many Ruby documentations” you mentioned, here is the [official one](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html).

Ruby parser does its best to understand and successfully parse the input; when it sees a syntax error, it tries another way. That said, syntax errors have greater precedence compared to *all* operator precedence rules.

Since LHO must be variable, it starts with *an assignment*. Here is the case when the parsing *can* be done with a default precedence order and `+` is done before `*=`:

```
age = 2
age *= age + 1
#⇒ 6
```

Comment: Slightly incorrect. `1 + age *= 2` is definitely what sees a parser (MRI `parse.y:new_op_assign`). The parser just happens to generate the same bytecode as `1 + age = age * 2`. +1 for the rest.

Comment: Yeah that official one also lists the binary operators as having higher precedence than the compound assignment operators. Ruby will forever amaze me.

Comment: @Amadan well, correct. I meant “the _thing_ that in MRI does a real execution.”

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Ok given that the syntactic sugar expands to `1 + age = age * 2`. How does it get parenthesized and evaluated then?

Comment: As it’s clearly stated in my answer, Ruby attempts `(1 + age) = ...`, fails to parse the syntactically correct expression (LHO is invalid,) and then tries `1 + (age = ...)` successfully.

Comment: "The code `1 + age *= 2` cannot be parenthesized in any way, because it’s not what sees a parser; it’s _syntactic sugar_ for" – Do you have any source for that statement? Preferably from the ISO Ruby Language Specification, the Ruby Spec, or *The Ruby Programming Language* book? I mean, how is the parser supposed to desugar the expression without parsing it? The parser *must* parse `a *= b` because how else would it know to desugar it to `a = a * b` and not say `a = a + b` without parsing it? Also, if the compound assignment operators are never parsed, then why are they documented in the …

Comment: … operator precedence table?

Comment: "I am not sure what “many Ruby documentations” you mentioned, here is the [official one](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html)." – That just shows the exact same thing the OP has been saying: that compound assignment has lower precedence than arithmetic, which is precisely the point of this question.

Comment: @JörgWMittag He clarified a couple of comments up that he actually meant VM ("the _thing_ that in MRI does a real execution"), not parser. Though I'd prefer it be changed in the answer :)

Comment: "Also, Ruby parser does it’s best to understand and successfully parse the input; when it sees a syntax error, it tries another way." – Do you have any source for that statement? Preferably from the ISO Ruby Language Specification, the Ruby Spec, or *The Ruby Programming Language* book? This is the first time I ever hear about this rule. The only language I know which has some kind of rule like that, is ECMAScript's *Automatic Semicolon Insertion* rule, which indeed requires that the code without the semicolon be syntactically illegal.

Comment: @Amadan: Then I am even more confused, since the question is about the syntax and grammar, not the semantics, so the evaluator is *completely and utterly irrelevant* to the question. The VM doesn't even know about Ruby at all, it only knows about YARV bytecode which is a different language than Ruby.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: You're quite right, I retract my +1. Ruby uses Bison, a LALR(1) parser - it can't do what Aleksei says it does.

Comment: If I am not mistaken [this branch of the code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y#L9026) hets executed when it sees `+`. That in turn routes to [`dispatch2`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y#L7875) which ecaluates RHO first.

Comment: That cannot happen, the branch you linked to is Ripper-only.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby has 3 phases before your code is actually executed.

> Tokenize -> Parse -> Compile

Let's look at the AST(Abstract Syntax Tree) Ruby generates which is the parse phase.

```
# @ NODE_SCOPE (line: 1, location: (1,0)-(1,12))
# | # new scope
# | # format: [nd_tbl]: local table, [nd_args]: arguments, [nd_body]: body
# +- nd_tbl (local table): :age
# +- nd_args (arguments):
# |   (null node)
# +- nd_body (body):
#     @ NODE_OPCALL (line: 1, location: (1,0)-(1,12))*
#     | # method invocation
#     | # format: [nd_recv] [nd_mid] [nd_args]
#     | # example: foo + bar
#     +- nd_mid (method id): :+
#     +- nd_recv (receiver):
#     |   @ NODE_LIT (line: 1, location: (1,0)-(1,1))
#     |   | # literal
#     |   | # format: [nd_lit]
#     |   | # example: 1, /foo/
#     |   +- nd_lit (literal): 1
#     +- nd_args (arguments):
#         @ NODE_ARRAY (line: 1, location: (1,4)-(1,12))
#         | # array constructor
#         | # format: [ [nd_head], [nd_next].. ] (length: [nd_alen])
#         | # example: [1, 2, 3]
#         +- nd_alen (length): 1
#         +- nd_head (element):
#         |   @ NODE_DASGN_CURR (line: 1, location: (1,4)-(1,12))
#         |   | # dynamic variable assignment (in current scope)
#         |   | # format: [nd_vid](current dvar) = [nd_value]
#         |   | # example: 1.times { x = foo }
#         |   +- nd_vid (local variable): :age
#         |   +- nd_value (rvalue):
#         |       @ NODE_CALL (line: 1, location: (1,4)-(1,12))
#         |       | # method invocation
#         |       | # format: [nd_recv].[nd_mid]([nd_args])
#         |       | # example: obj.foo(1)
#         |       +- nd_mid (method id): :*
#         |       +- nd_recv (receiver):
#         |       |   @ NODE_DVAR (line: 1, location: (1,4)-(1,7))
#         |       |   | # dynamic variable reference
#         |       |   | # format: [nd_vid](dvar)
#         |       |   | # example: 1.times { x = 1; x }
#         |       |   +- nd_vid (local variable): :age
#         |       +- nd_args (arguments):
#         |           @ NODE_ARRAY (line: 1, location: (1,11)-(1,12))
#         |           | # array constructor
#         |           | # format: [ [nd_head], [nd_next].. ] (length: [nd_alen])
#         |           | # example: [1, 2, 3]
#         |           +- nd_alen (length): 1
#         |           +- nd_head (element):
#         |           |   @ NODE_LIT (line: 1, location: (1,11)-(1,12))
#         |           |   | # literal
#         |           |   | # format: [nd_lit]
#         |           |   | # example: 1, /foo/
#         |           |   +- nd_lit (literal): 2
#         |           +- nd_next (next element):
#         |               (null node)
#         +- nd_next (next element):
#             (null node)
```

As you can see `#     +- nd_mid (method id): :+` where `1` is treated as the receiver and everything on the right as arguments. Now, it goes further and does its best to evaluate the arguments.

To further support Aleksei's great answer. The `@ NODE_DASGN_CURR (line: 1, location: (1,4)-(1,12))` is the assignment on `age` as a local variable as it decodes it as `age = age * 2`, which is why `+- nd_mid (method id): :*` is treated as the operation on `age` as the receiver and `2` as its argument.

Now when it goes on to compile it tries as operation: `age * 2` where `age` is nil because it already parsed it as a local variable with no pre-assigned value, raises exception `undefined method '*' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`.

It works the way it did is cause any operation on the receiver must have an evaluated argument from the RHO.

Comment: "Ruby has 3 phases before your code is actually executed.

> Parse -> Tokenize -> Compile" – Like every other parser in the history of computing, tokenization (aka lexical analysis aka scanning) happens *before* parsing (aka syntactic analysis), with the exception of scannerless parsers that don't do tokenization / lexing / scanning at all.